# runtime.js file always romoved when I install other packages

Tags: javascript

Whenever I install some packages, `runtime.js in regenerator-runtime` always removed..

So I always have prepared that files in other folder and pasted when I install some..

It's very vexing thing to me.

It's all same in my all projects where I have this package

who know why this happen??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happens.

just uninstall all node packages and reinstall them then, this problem go away..

1. Remove yarn.lock (or package.lock)
2. yarn (npm install)